# Cannot get HTML/CSS modal box to open up and display on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using JQuery I'm trying to let the user select an image that is displayed in on the html page using the below code. This is then displayed in the modal box via `#badgeselect`

At the moment the modal box is not being opened after the user clicks the image. It looks like it might be trying to place it on the actual main page and not in the modal box.

I can make the box appear successfully using

```
<a href="#modal" title="Clicking this link shows the modal">Demo Show</a>
```

But I'm wondering if

```
$(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');
```

is the issue for it not working?

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.go img').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $('.go').on('click', 'img', function(e) {
                $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');

                $('#modal1').reveal({

                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Modal box

```
        <!-- A modal with its content -->
<section class="modal--show" id="modal1"
        tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="label-show" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-inner">
        <header>
            <h2 id="label-show">A modal</h2>
        </header>

        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>Content.</p>
            <div id="badgeselect"></div>

        <select id="selectFriend">
            <option>Select friend</option>
        </select>

        <textarea id="UploaderComment" rows="5" cols="30">Add a comment</textarea>

                        <a id="send" class="button green close">
            <img src="images/tick.png">Confirm</a>

        <a href="http://example.com/page.html" class="button red close">
            <img src="images/cross.png">Cancel</a>


        </div>

        <footer>
            <p>Footer</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <a href="#!" class="modal-close" title="Close this modal"
            data-dismiss="modal" data-close="Close">&times;</a>
</section>

    <!-- END -->
```

Comment: Nothing, but on clicking it looks like the images are being added to the main page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to load the reveal modal to get the img in the modal popup

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.go img').css('cursor', 'pointer'); 
       $('.go').on('click', 'img', function(e) {

       $('#modal1').reveal({ }); return false; 
        }); 
   $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');
   });
```

Comment: Cheers, do I need to use the .reveal ? can I just open it after the user has clicked on the image?

Comment: Yes .reveal is to be used...or you can make use of the inline thing data-reveal-id="myModal".Did that work by the way?

Comment: In some ways, but it lead me to another question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978998/unable-to-make-modal-box-appear-using-jquery