# Unable to make modal box appear using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using JQuery I'm trying to get a modal box to open after a click is made on an image. I can make the box open using a hard link, but not when the user clicks the image. I've tried using .show but this does'doesn't seem correct?

Example fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/63VeU/13/

The below code structure using .go etc must remain as thats how the images are identified that they can be clicked on.

I know this is a rookie, question, but I'm unable to find the anser I need anywhere.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.go img').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $('.go').on('click', 'img', function(e) {
                $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#modal-show');
                $( "#modal-show" ).show( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
                SaveMyBadge();
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: What modal are you using? jQuery dialog?

Comment: @Dejan.S this one http://drublic.github.io/css-modal/#%21 even though its css/html I thought I could still access it via JQ?

Comment: Well you can solve this in different ways. Why don't you just wrap the image with a-tag?

Comment: If you could give an example I can accept this as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Here you got a working demo. I noticed you do some additional stuff like `SaveMyBadge();` so updated the fiddle.

```
<a href="#modal-show" title="Clicking this link shows the modal">
    <img class="images BadgeImgOutline responsive-image" src="http://kudosoo.com/GBadges/badge9.jpg" alt="badge-image" />
</a>


$(document).on('click', '.click-badge', function () {
    //do other stuff if you need to

    SaveMyBadge();
    return false;
});
```